# WPF: What can be used as Source for Collection​View​Source

Tags: wpf, collectionviewsource

I would like to know, which classes and/or interfaces can be assigned to the WPF `Collection​View​Source.​Source Property`. The help documentation doesn't explain anything:

```
public object Source { get; set; }
```

There is no explanation nor code sample and since `Source` is of type `object`, anything can be assigned. I guess `Source` is supporting various interfaces as sources, but which ones ?

I know for example that it works with a `List<>`, which implements a number of interfaces. I guess the most basic of them is `IEnumerable<T>`. Does `Source` accept anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>` and the reason that `Source` is of type `object` is because it has to support also `IEnumerable` ? What else does it support ? Does it take advantage if a higher interface like `IList<>` is also implemented ?

**To all of you who simply cannot resist to mark a question as duplicate:**

It's quite frustrating if you mark a question as duplicate and prevent any further answers, just because you have seen somewhere an answer assigning something to `Collection​View​Source.Source`. There are many of them. But please note that this question does not ask just for one example, but I would like to know everything that can be assigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Data/CollectionViewSource.cs,8d41d294959bd755):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "Source",
                    typeof(object),
                    typeof(CollectionViewSource),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                            (object)null,
                            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSourceChanged)),
                    new ValidateValueCallback(IsSourceValid));
```

Let's see how IsSourceValid is implemented:

```
private static bool IsSourceValid(object o)
{
    return (o == null ||
            o is IEnumerable ||
            o is IListSource ||
            o is DataSourceProvider) &&
            !(o is ICollectionView);
}
```

Thus, valid types are:

- **IEnumerable**
- **IListSource**
- **DataSourceProvider**

**ICollectionView is invalid** source.

Comment: ...and `!(o is ICollectionView)` is necessary because [`ICollectionView` is `IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx). Excellent answer.

Comment: The sad thing is that I tried to check myself on referencesource but couldn't find the class Collection​View​Source, so I guessed WPF is not there. I wonder why someone -1 my question. Can someone +1 it ?